# Do items in Dota 2 have individual cooldowns?

Tags: dota-2

If I buy 2 [Quelling Blades](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Quelling_Blade), does that I mean I can hack down trees twice as fast?

Similarly, if I buy two [Linken's Spheres](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Linken's_Sphere), can I block two spells?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Items have shared cooldown. If you buy 2 quelling blades and uses one, both will be on cd.

As for BKB, it will make you untargetable (Not invunerable, there are some skills/items that goes through bkb.) for spells for X of time, considering the number of times you used it.

Comment: Hey fernandofleury! Welcome to Arqade! Thanks for a great answer! Do you have a link to an external source that explains this in more detail?

Comment: @BBz there's nothing to add, really. The only thing I can think of is that Lone Druid can use two Hand of Midas with one on his bear.

Comment: @BBZ as for the BKB subject, here is the complete list of skills/items that pierces bkb http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Magic_immunity

Answer (score 5):

No, items of the same type share a cooldown as long as they're on the same hero **or companion**.  Items in different inventories do *not* share a cooldown.  Also note that a Refresher Orb will not refresh its own cooldown even if you have multiple instances of it (in case you might think "hey it refreshes the cooldown of *other* inventory items first but then they share the reset cooldown").

The most notable instance where the subtle clarification with companions is important is on Lone Druid.  You *can* have items with separate cooldowns on both you and your Spirit Bear.  So, a two Hand of Midas build is actually doable and they do not share a cooldown as they are in different inventories.  A more common but less intriguing example would be Phase Boots.  You can have Phase Boots on both you and your Spirit Bear and they will *not* share a cooldown either, meaning if you had phased with one recently it will not affect your ability to phase with the other.

Note that this does *not* apply to things like Beastmaster's hawk and boar as they don't have inventories you can put items in.